# Inexplicable Offset in Satellite Laser Ranging (SLR) observations

Tags: artificial-satellite, attitude, navigation, gps, earth-observation

I am struggling with the implementation of a [Satellite Laser Ranging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_laser_ranging) (SLR) validation tool.

The situation is as follows: I am provided with a framework which gives me the position of a SLR observation station and the position of a satellite at a specified GPS time. Those positions can be assumed to be sufficiently correct for the given task. From those positions I calculate a reference distance which I will use for comparison with given SLR observations. The observation files I use as input are in CRD format and provided by data centers like http://edc.dgfi.tum.de/en/. From those files I extract, for each observation record, the GPS time stamp and time of flight in seconds. According to the simplest observation equation for SLR given by
 $$d = c * \frac{\Delta t}{2}$$
I calculate the distance between station and satellite and compare it to the distance provided by my framework.

The problem is the distances deviate seemingly randomly with deviations ranging from 1 to 300 meters in both directions. I am aware that the simple observation equation is missing all correction terms but even without those an accuracy of up to 10 meters should be feasible.

So far I thought I was dealing with a station clock or observation clock bias but adding offsets in positive as well as negative direction to the observation times always resulted in greater deviations of the two distances.

The only thing I am constantly experiencing in all observations is (surprisingly) a greater deviation at steeper elevation angles, which is in contrast to my expectations, since this results in far shorter absolute distances.

One example of my results is the following [observation from Graz Lustbühel of the 22 June 2017 monitoring the GRACE A satellite](http://edc.dgfi.tum.de/en/data/npt/1443408/).

```
 | standard Deviation 156.32185
 |  Time               | Ref Distance| Obs Distance| Deviation   | Elevation Angle
 | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | 2017-06-22_13-57-47 | 573630.53   | 573510.16   | -124.37518  | 34.1093
 | 2017-06-22_13-57-51 | 550922.4    | 550796.16   | -130.05672  | 35.989845
 | 2017-06-22_13-57-56 | 528348.25   | 528215.69   | -136.19948  | 38.060675
 | 2017-06-22_13-58-00 | 507464.43   | 507325.52   | -142.39058  | 40.19135
 | 2017-06-22_13-58-06 | 484607.77   | 484461.27   | -149.80929  | 42.81356
 | 2017-06-22_13-58-11 | 465610.45   | 465457.04   | -156.57817  | 45.279134
 | 2017-06-22_13-58-16 | 449075.77   | 448915.81   | -162.99763  | 47.689646
 | 2017-06-22_13-58-20 | 435233      | 435067.11   | -168.8336   | 49.94278
 | 2017-06-22_13-58-25 | 424230.88   | 424059.89   | -173.84746  | 51.921769
 | 2017-06-22_13-58-30 | 415972.62   | 415797.47   | -177.94548  | 53.540971
 | 2017-06-22_13-58-35 | 411432.82   | 411255.13   | -180.45426  | 54.491375
 | 2017-06-22_13-58-40 | 409363.89   | 409184.61   | -182.0285   | 54.951053
 | 2017-06-22_13-58-46 | 411421.31   | 411242.31   | -181.76171  | 54.532429
 | 2017-06-22_13-58-50 | 416021.81   | 415844.36   | -180.23949  | 53.598194
 | 2017-06-22_13-58-56 | 427050      | 426876.64   | -176.23183  | 51.499173
 | 2017-06-22_13-58-59 | 433701.19   | 433530.31   | -173.80953  | 50.323281
 | 2017-06-22_13-59-06 | 452168.09   | 452003.85   | -167.28999  | 47.357755
 | 2017-06-22_13-59-11 | 468417.38   | 468258.68   | -161.8747   | 45.049964
 | 2017-06-22_13-59-15 | 487200.93   | 487048.25   | -155.9925   | 42.663639
 | 2017-06-22_13-59-21 | 509791.27   | 509645.32   | -149.43676  | 40.116813
 | 2017-06-22_13-59-26 | 532186.88   | 532047.1    | -143.43855  | 37.873845
 | 2017-06-22_13-59-30 | 555171.16   | 555037.25   | -137.7555   | 35.809979
 | 2017-06-22_13-59-35 | 580787.28   | 580659.4    | -131.91771  | 33.744171
 | 2017-06-22_13-59-40 | 607376.04   | 607253.94   | -126.36003  | 31.816812
 | 2017-06-22_14-00-11 | 792767.05   | 792675.37   | -97.569278  | 22.258777
```

Is there any phenomenon explaining this varying offsets?

Comment: You calculate the distance between a satellite and a ground station from the time interval. But what value do you use for the speed of light? The vacuum value is valid above the atmosphere but not within. GPS uses a correction for the influence of the atmosphere to the speed of light. Of course the correction depends on air pressure at the altitude. But this error is very small, for a GPS satellite 5 ° above the horizon up to 25 m. If you want a accuracy better than 10 m, the lower speed of light within atmosphere should be considered. But errors up to 300 m are not explained by this effect.

Comment: During one nanosecond, a distance of about 0.3 m is covered by light. For a precision of less than 10 m, the resolution and precision of time measurement should be less than about 10 ns.

Comment: For the speed of light I have used the constant given at [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light]. I am aware of the atmospheric delay and I have already implemented respective correction functions based on the algorithms by **Marini and Murray** as well as **Mendes and Pavlis**. But I have switched them off again for debugging since they influence the results only marginally.

Comment: I didn't find the precision of the time of flight in the format specification https://ilrs.cddis.eosdis.nasa.gov/docs/2009/crd_v1.01.pdf, but since biases are given in ps and the data being meant for exactly this calculation I am quite sure the error is not due to insufficient precision.

Comment: Are you certain you're using the same time system/reference in both cases?

Comment: The framework uses GPS time and the observations (according to the format specification) too.

Comment: Are you sure that for all variables during computation at least double precision floating point is used? 15 to 17 significant decimal digits should be ok for ps resolution, but 6 to 9 significant decimal digits precision for single precision is not ok.

Comment: What is the accuracy of GPS time stamps? GPS satellite clocks are synchronized to a deviation less than 20 ns seconds only. Nanoseconds but not picoseconds. Ground based atomic clocks for UTC are synchronized better than 10 ns.

Comment: The implementation is in C++ and all variables holding time stamps are declared as `double` which should precise enough. I have checked the output of the variables and no significant decimal digits seem to be truncated.

Comment: The accuracy of satellite clocks is in this case of no relevance since only two-way measurements are considered - the laser beam is reflected at the satellite and all the time measurement is done at the ground station with a sufficiently accurate clock. Station clock bias are (if present) also given in the observation files.

Comment: Perhaps a reference frame issue? What frame, specifically, is the satellite position given in?

Comment: The station positions are in TRF and the satellite positions in ITRF. But the transformation between the frames is done by algorithms which are also used for an abundance of other applications, yielding correct results. For the comparison of the distances the frame in which the satellite positions are given is no longer of relevance.

Comment: Just to make shure I did understand it right: You take two way distance measurements using laser pulses from ground station to satellite and back. You compare those distances with distances computed from ground station and satellite position. You need the position of the satellite at the moment of reflection of the laser pulse. The distances are between 400 to 800 km, for two way measurement the time delay is 2.7 ms to 5.3 ms. But the satellite is moving with about 8 km/s, for 10 m precision, the time of the satellite position should be better than 1.25 ms.

Comment: The point with two way distance measurement is correct. I am not computing any positions though, but I just want to get the SLR distance as precise as possible with adding various corrections as next step. The satellite position is given and I already take the time of reflection given by time of transmission + time of flight/2. For the ground station I also take this time stamp which is apparently not completely correct since the ground station moves until the the signal is received but this movement is even in the worst case (at equator) sufficiently small.

Answer (score 4):

A few things to consider:

1. Refraction- The atmosphere will bend the light somewhat, which might cause it to take longer.
2. Speed of light changes- Light moves a bit slower when going through more of the atmosphere
3. Timing accuracy- The position of the satellite might be off in time slightly, which would result in a deviation.
4. Positional accuracy- This results if you don't know the location of your source point exactly.
5. Floating point errors. Floating points are accurate to about 7 decimal digits. That means it is accurate to about a meter, give or take. Not likely to be the source of your error, but it could crop up in the time estimates.

To narrow this down a bit, try the following:

1. See if there is a correlation between the error and the line of sight angle. If the distance is most accurate when straight overhead, it could be a refraction or speed of light error.
2. Make sure your GPS location and time are accurate.
3. Try plotting various of your values vs others.
4. Determine the distance to a known source. I recommend using the Lunar laser reflectors on the moon. With these, you can get great results. If you are able to do this with satellites, consider using one of the GPS satellites, as their exact positions can easily be calculated.

Looking at your data, I found a few things of some interest.

1. The higher the elevation, the higher the error. This would indicate an overcorrection.
2. The relative error is highest at the highest angles.

Thinking about this, that indicates that when the overhead motion of the satellite is the most, the error is the most. Also when the Doppler change is the most, the error is the most. I rather strongly suspect the issue is some kind of a timing issue, where the exact position of an object isn't as well determined as you think it is. Try some of the tests I indicated (Moon and GPS satellites) if you can to further validate this.

Comment: Single precision floating point error is about 7 decimal digits, but double precision is 15 to 17 digits. There is also quadruple precison using 128 bits giving 33 to 36 decimal digits.

Comment: If it's not the issue with single precision, double precision won't be an issue. But yes, if one was tracking a ~1m error, then going to double precision would greatly drop that error.

Comment: The time of flight in seconds are given with 12 decimal digits, so double precision should be sufficient. Hence all calculations have been conducted with double precision.